# Best practices for Creating an enterprise Desktop Application with a database

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, spring

I don't have much experience on Java based enterprise desktop applications. I need to create an enterprise application with the database. Can you please tell me what are the technologies (hibernate, spring), design patterns that I need to use to create then enterprise java desktop application. Also I want to know about how can I create a final installer for this application on windows

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I hope you've read the [FAQ on what questions can be asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). I'm afraid the question in the current form is overtly broad. Without knowing about your design and it's issues, one cannot propose a pattern to use, therefore asking about design patterns to use would result in ambiguous answers.

Comment: @Stephen, yes. Can't edit the typo though.

Answer (score 1):

Despite you question is too general i will give it a try:

Java desktop:
As front end you have:

1. swing (very mature and stable ,with
   a lot of samples documentation)
2. javafx (latest thing , but not very
   popular yet)
3. jambi qt (a java wrapper over Qt ,ui
   framework).

There are other scripting languages that offer implementations over swing.

Now you desktop app might be : a fat client or a thin client :)
Shortly fat client handles a lot of logic on client side compared to thin client who is more 
used only as a presentation view.
Fat cleints were popular before web era in the so called 2 tier architectures.
Thing client were popular before the era of RIA Desktop apps. (GWT,FLex)

On server side if you use java you have an immensity of choices: for persistance layer
Hibernate,Eclipse Link with or without JPA2,Ibatis...
Spring or Jee6 you can choose as frameworks for all sever side layers...cause they have everything :)

However If you rephrase you question people might gave you more concrete answers